# How do we know the output `a` has the same value as input `a` in the type signature (a,b) -> a

Tags: haskell

I'm reading a book *Haskell Programming From First Principles*. On p. 122 authors highlight `fst` function:

`fst :: (a, b) -> a`

> The result of the function, which has type `a`. It’s the same `a` that
> was in the tuple `(a, b)`.
> How do we know it’s the same `a`? We can say that we know the
> input type `a` and the output type `a` must be the same type, and we can
> see that nothing happens between the input and the output; that is,
> there is no operation that comes between them that could transform
> that `a` into some other value of that type.

Also earlier, p. 107, in reference to `fst` and `snd`:

> The type signature tells us there’s nothing those functions could
> do other than return the first or second value, respectively.

I don't get this. If `a` had a typeclass constraint like `Num a => (a, b) -> a` the function could easily add 3 to the first argument of the tuple and return something of the same type `a` but a different value, and this would not show up in the type signature of the function. Is the point that you couldn't really do anything to the input tuple without some typeclass constraint? Or without knowing that the input is e.g. a list, as in `tail :: [a] -> [a]`, by which we just know based on our knowledge of lists that `tail` could be adding or removing elements to/from the input? Even without a typeclass constraint, couldn't `(a, b) -> a` just return some arbitrary constant of type `a`, not necessarily the first element in the tuple?

How do the authors come to this conclusion?

Comment: But it has no type constraint, hence there is no function like `+`, `-`, etc. that you can use. The only option would be `undefined` or a function that calls itself and thus gets stuck in an infinite loop, but that is non-sensical. See for example [*djinn*](https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/djinn/) that can for simple types exhaustively produce all possible functions.

Comment: I find this is a very interesting question. I hadn't ever thought about it, but I can't think of anything you can actualy do with a type without knowing what typeclasses it honors. (Clearly if you don't write the signature, the compiler will be able to infer what typeclass is needed.)

Comment: The classic reference is [Theorems for free!](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/99370.99404)

Comment: Thanks for all the links, they are useful. I figured this was a dupe but couldn't come up with the right search. Really just the *Real World Haskell* quote from the other question clarifies it enough.

Comment: Regarding your `f :: [a] -> [a]` example: such a function can only discard or duplicate elements from the input. That is, `f [1,2,3]` can not return `[3,3,7,1]` because of the `7`. At best, it can  introduce new "bottom" elements. Also, if `f [1,2,3]` is `[1,1,3]`, then `f "abc"` must be `"aac"`, since there is no way for `f` to act differently -- `f` can only "blindly move around" the values of type `a` without knowing what they actually are.

Comment: "couldn't (a, b) -> a just return some arbitrary constant of type a"  How would it get a constant of type `a`, without having any constraint about `a`?

Comment: My thought was a lookup table based on the real type of `a`, but 1) that could never be comprehensive and 2) that information is not available anyway.